# Extending custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, oop, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewController say XViewController.
In my project, I have 20 viewcontrollers.
I need to extend viewcontrollers from XViewController so that I access properties in XViewController. 
I need to make change as
 AViewController : XViewController
 BViewController : XViewController

.......

in all classes.
But I do not want to make this change in all classes.

Is there any smart way like using Categories to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any smart way like using Categories to achieve this ?

**No.** If your various controllers need to descend from `XViewController`, you need to specify that in each of the class declarations. The superclass isn't something that you can bolt on after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you need every controller to have shared properties, you will have to make changes to every controller to extend from your parent controller.

You can use category for properties that are shared among all controllers, that don't necessarily follow the `extends` relation. There is a difference.